# Best software for 3D modeling and simulation semiconductors?

Tags: modeling, finite-element-method, simulation, software

Need to design 3D model of photodiode and calculate it (interaction light with semiconductor). What software product would be better for this objective and why?

**Important criteria:**

1. Big library semiconductor elements.
2. Comfortable interface
3. Small expensive CPU\GPU (high speed of calculate).
4. Price of product.
5. Ability to import geometry from autocad\solidworks etc.

Comment: I would suggest either looking for reviews online and determining the best fit on your own, or talking to other engineers who do the same work and ask them what they use. It's hard to come up with an objectively 'best' software for any application, and product recommendations are not on-topic here, which is why this question is attracting close votes